# Proper way of making an Asynchronous request in Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, httprequest, swift2

I am learning swift slowly and mostly by googling problems as I encounter them.

From researching online I have found one rule:

**

### Never make Synchronous requests & Always make Asynchronous requests

**

But there are so many different ways people are making requests online thats its confusing to figure out which one is the correct one. And as Apple recently released Swift 2 few of the methods have become deprecated. Which means most of the examples or answers on the net have also become deprecated.

Currently I am using the below code to make requests. I don't know whether this is the correct way of making a request or whether this is Asynchronous.

```
  let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "www.domain.com")!)
  let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
    let _: NSError?

    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, err -> Void in

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true

    print("Response: \(response)")
    let strData = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    print("Body: \(strData)")
    do {
             self.json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableLeaves) as? NSArray
        } catch {

      }

    })

    task.resume()
```

My questions for this post are as follows:

1. **Why is an Asynchronous request better?**
2. **What are the steps involved in making an Asynchronous request in Swift 2?**

If you can provide some example code that would be very helpful.

P.s ( ***I am posting here after searching hours on the net and I have read quite a few posts on stack overflow, so I would humbly request that please don't post links to other stack overflow post as an answer, post them as comments*** )

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why is an Asynchronous request better?

Doesn't block the interface while the (possibly very time-consuming) request and reply happens over the network. Blocking the interface is bad, plus the system will kill your app dead right before the user's eyes if it does this for too long.

> What are the steps involved in making an Asynchronous request in Swift 2?

Use NSURLSession. This call in your code is asynchronous, because you are using NSURLSession:

```
let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler:{
    data, response, err -> Void in
    // this code runs asynchronously...
    // ... i.e. later, after the request has completed (or failed)
})
```